# LINQ-to-SQL Insert... Select... Where... in one query

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I have a problem with Linq to duplicate a line with selected columns ?? I have an SQL query but I would like to use Linq for this purpose. Thank you for your response.

```sql
insert into [ManageSales].[dbo].[Inwestycje_test] (Id_KI, Nazwa)
select Id_KI, Nazwa
from [ManageSales].[dbo].[Inwestycje_test]
where id = 1
```

Comment: You have to write two minimum operation..first for select and than insert in Linq as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var insert = from i in db.Inwestycje_test
               where i.id = 1 
               select new 
               {
                   i.Id_KI,
                   i.Nazwa
               };
db.Inwestycje_test.InsertAllOnSubmit(insert);
db.SubmitChanges();
```